# disallow to include parent path

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there any compiler flag (or other method) that disallow include like following

```
#include "../lib.h"
```

but still allows you to include libs in current context and its childs

```
#include "lib.h"
#include "directory/lib.h"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @CarlNorum
That what I have wrote?
If I write `#include` with reference to parent directory I want `lib.h` not to be included. It may throw error or just simply act like this line was never there (if including file use something from included file it throws undefined reference anyway), but in any case this file cannot be included.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such flag that one can pass to perform this.

I suspect that one could craft some calls to other programs in the compiler call, but that is starting to become a maintenance nightmare.

Rather, one should look into the features offered by the build system used for the project and see if it offers any forms of checks that can be run before compilation.